# Error when precompiling all handlebars templates files in one js file

Tags: javascript, npm, handlebars.js, template-engine

Here's my folder structure:

```
app
└───templates
    ├───templ1.hbs
    ├───templ2.hbs
    └───templ3.hbs
```

I want to compile (precompile) all templN.hbs handlebars template files in one templ.js file, but when i try to do it via console

```
$ handlebars *.hbs -f templ.js
```

compiling fails with this error

```
(...)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\handlebars\bin\handlebars:120
    throw err;
    ^
 Error: Unable to open template file "*.hbs"
    at (...)\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\precompiler.js:107:25
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

What's the matter?

Comment: Did you make sure you've changed the active directory into the correct folder? Most likely it's barfing because it's looking for `templ1.hbs` but you're actually running the command from `~/Desktop` or something.

Comment: @Titus When I run that command from cmd I'm in the `app/templates/` folder. In fact compiling a single template such as templ1.hbs with `$ handlebars templ1.hbs -f templ1.js` works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*After a bit of practice with Handlebars and its precompiler i found out the solution was as simple as stupid my question was.*

First of all it's better to stay in the root folder, hence in my case stay in `app` folder. Then, to compile all .hbs templates, simply pass the entire `./handlebars` folder as input to handlebars precompiler and specify the extension of templates he should look for:

```
$ handlebars ./templates -f templ.js --extension "hbs"
```

Everything should work fine.

*For more precompiler's options see http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html*